# Swift: override associatedtype from protocol extension in protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

So, I'm trying to achieve this:

Have a protocol with associatedtype who will handle json parsing into his extension. The associatedtype must conform to `Decodable`:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype ResponseType: Decodable
  func handleResponse(data: Data) -> ResponseType
}
```

What I'm want to do is to set a default type for responseType into my extension and then, if needed, override that type into the class, or struct conformance. Something like this.

```
extension MyProtocol {
  typealias ResponseType = MyDefaultDecodableType

  func handleResponse(data: Data) -> ResponseType { ... }
}

class MyObject: MyProtocol {
  typealias ResponseType = AnotherDecodableType
}
```

Problem is I'm getting an error like this inside `MyObject`:

```
error: type 'MyObject' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'
class MyObject: MyProtocol {
      ^
note: multiple matching types named 'ResponseType'
    associatedtype ResponseType: Decodable
                   ^
note: possibly intended match
  typealias ResponseType = AnotherDecodableType
            ^
note: possibly intended match
    public typealias ResponseType = MyDefaultDecodableType
```

I don't know if it's possible to achieve what I'm trying or I'm approaching the wrong way. Anyone can give me some light?

Thanks.

Comment: How does your MyDefaultDecodableType and  AnotherDecodableType look ?

Comment: AnotherDecodableType and  MyDefaultDecodableType is confirming `Decodable` protocol ?

Comment: Thanks you accepting answer i am glad that it helps you :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the same code. There are some facts that need to be understood here.

```
extension MyProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = MyDefaultDecodableType
    
    func handleResponse(data: Data) -> ResponseType {
        
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyDefaultDecodableType.self, from: data)
        
    }
}
```

Conceptually, there are no generic protocols in Swift. But by using `typealias` we can declare a required alias for another type.

Your extension  doesn't need to define  `typealias ResponseType = MyDefaultDecodableType` as it is going to provide some default implementation using `MyDefaultDecodableType`, so it is useless.

So your extension would be something like this

```
extension MyProtocol {
  //  typealias ResponseType = MyDefaultDecodableType // NO NEED FOR IT
    
    func handleResponse(data: Data) -> MyDefaultDecodableType {
        print("Test \(self)")
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyDefaultDecodableType.self, from: data)
        
    }
}
```

Now you can define

```
class MyObject:MyProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = AnotherDecodableType
    
    func handleResponse(data: Data) -> ResponseType {
        print("Test \(self)")

        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(AnotherDecodableType.self, from: data)
        
    }
    
}
class MyObject2:MyProtocol {
   
    
}
```

Without any errors

Now if you use

```
MyObject().handleResponse(data:data)
MyObject2().handleResponse(data:data2)
```

You will get

> test __lldb_expr_44.MyObject
>
> test __lldb_expr_44.MyObject2